# Laravel Tracker not producing results

Tags: laravel, session, statistics, tracker

I have laravel 5.4, I have installed tracker, but I am not getting results thus far.  I’m not sure if my publish statement worked properly as it published migrations but no models.  I was wondering if this was correct.

https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker

I was also wondering how to call the template pages that gets set up on git statements.  I have ran those in the files of downloaded, but the route does not open that I have configured in my tracker configuration file.  Is there a list of routes that I’d need to add to my route file.

When I called tracker, I do not get an error of not being found, but I also only have gotten null datasets returned.

Any help that can be given would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you for your time.  I followed the directions as closely as I could, but some information is missing for configuring to laravel 5.4.

I’m currently using file sessions if that matters.  It does not say anything about meeting the change that.

***I should mention that I have a multi authentication system within my web middleware.  Both guards are built into the web middleware.  I don’t think this is the issue as I am temporarily trying to view the stats page as logged in as a normal user.

tracker Config file

```
<?php
return [
    /*
     * Enable it?
     */
    'enabled' => true,
    /*
     * Enable cache?
     */
    'cache_enabled' => true,
    /*
     * Deffer booting for middleware use
     */
    'use_middleware' => true,
    /*
     * Robots should be tracked?
     */
    'do_not_track_robots' => false,
    /*
     * Which environments are not trackable?
     */
    'do_not_track_environments' => [
        // defaults to none
    ],
    /*
     * Which routes names are not trackable?
     */
    'do_not_track_routes' => [
        'tracker.stats.*',
    ],
    /*
     * The Do Not Track Ips is used to disable Tracker for some IP addresses:
     *
     *     '127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.1'
     *
     * You can set ranges of IPs
     *     '192.168.0.1-192.168.0.100'
     *
     * And use net masks
     *     '10.0.0.0/32'
     *     '172.17.0.0/255.255.0.0'
     */
    'do_not_track_ips' => [
    //    '127.0.0.0/24', /// range 127.0.0.1 - 127.0.0.255
    ],
    /*
     * Log every single access?
     *
     * The log table can become huge if your site is popular, but...
     *
     * Log table is also responsible for storing information on:
     *
     *    - Routes and controller actions accessed
     *    - HTTP method used (GET, POST...)
     *    - Error log
     *    - URL queries (including values)
     */
    'log_enabled' => false,
    /*
     * Log SQL queries?
     *
     * Log must be enabled for this option to work.
     */
    'log_sql_queries' => false,
    /*
     * If you prefer to store Tracker data on a different database or connection,
     * you can set it here.
     *
     * To avoid SQL queries log recursion, create a different connection for Tracker,
     * point it to the same database (or not) and forbid logging of this connection in
     * do_not_log_sql_queries_connections.
     */
    'connection' => 'tracker',
    /*
     * Forbid logging of SQL queries for some connections.
     *
     * To avoid recursion, you better ignore Tracker connection here.
     *
     * Please create a separate database connection for Tracker. It can hit
     * the same database of your application, but the connection itself
     * has to have a different name, so the package can ignore its own queries
     * and avoid recursion.
     *
     */
    'do_not_log_sql_queries_connections' => [
        'tracker',
    ],
    /*
     * Also log SQL query bindings?
     *
     * Log must be enabled for this option to work.
     */
    'log_sql_queries_bindings' => false,
    /*
     * Log events?
     */
    'log_events' => false,
    /*
     * Which events do you want to log exactly?
     */
    'log_only_events' => [
        // defaults to logging all events
    ],
    /*
     * What are the names of the id columns on your system?
     *
     * 'id' is the most common, but if you have one or more different,
     * please add them here in your preference order.
     */
    'id_columns_names' => [
        'id',
    ],
    /*
     * Do not log events for the following patterns.
     * Strings accepts wildcards:
     *
     *    eloquent.*
     *
     */
    'do_not_log_events' => [
        'illuminate.log',
        'eloquent.*',
        'router.*',
        'composing: *',
        'creating: *',
    ],
    /*
     * Do you wish to log Geo IP data?
     *
     * You will need to install the geoip package
     *
     *     composer require "geoip/geoip":"~1.14"
     *
     * And remove the PHP module
     *
     *     sudo apt-get purge php5-geoip
     *
     */
    'log_geoip' => false,
    /*
     * Do you wish to log the user agent?
     */
    'log_user_agents' => false,
    /*
     * Do you wish to log your users?
     */
    'log_users' => false,
    /*
     * Do you wish to log devices?
     */
    'log_devices' => false,
    /*
     * Do you wish to log languages?
     */
    'log_languages' => false,
    /*
     * Do you wish to log HTTP referers?
     */
    'log_referers' => false,
    /*
     * Do you wish to log url paths?
     */
    'log_paths' => false,
    /*
     * Do you wish to log url queries and query arguments?
     */
    'log_queries' => false,
    /*
     * Do you wish to log routes and route parameters?
     */
    'log_routes' => false,
    /*
     * Log errors and exceptions?
     */
    'log_exceptions' => false,
    /*
     * A cookie may be created on your visitor device, so you can have information
     * on everything made using that device on your site.    *
     */
    'store_cookie_tracker' => false,
    /*
     * If you are storing cookies, you better change it to a name you of your own.
     */
    'tracker_cookie_name' => 'please_change_this_cookie_name',
    /*
     * Internal tracker session name.
     */
    'tracker_session_name' => 'tracker_session',
    /*
     * ** IMPORTANT **
     *   Change the user model to your own.
     */
    'user_model' => 'App\User',
    /*
     * You can use your own model for every single table Tracker has.
     */
    'session_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Session',
    'log_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Log',
    'path_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Path',
    'query_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Query',
    'query_argument_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\QueryArgument',
    'agent_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Agent',
    'device_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Device',
    'cookie_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Cookie',
    'domain_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Domain',
    'referer_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Referer',
    'referer_search_term_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\RefererSearchTerm',
    'route_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Route',
    'route_path_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\RoutePath',
    'route_path_parameter_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\RoutePathParameter',
    'error_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Error',
    'geoip_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\GeoIp',
    'sql_query_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\SqlQuery',
    'sql_query_binding_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\SqlQueryBinding',
    'sql_query_binding_parameter_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\SqlQueryBindingParameter',
    'sql_query_log_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\SqlQueryLog',
    'connection_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Connection',
    'event_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Event',
    'event_log_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\EventLog',
    'system_class_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\SystemClass',
    'language_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Language',
    /*
     * Laravel internal variables on user authentication and login.
     */
    'authentication_ioc_binding' => ['auth','admin'], // defaults to 'auth' in Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth
    'authenticated_check_method' => 'check', // to Auth::check()
    'authenticated_user_method' => 'user', // to Auth::user()
    'authenticated_user_id_column' => 'id', // to Auth::user()->id
    'authenticated_user_username_column' => 'email', // to Auth::user()->email
    /*
     * Enable the Stats Panel?
     */
    'stats_panel_enabled' => false,
    /*
     * Stats Panel routes before filter
     *
     */
    'stats_routes_before_filter' => '',
    /*
     * Stats Panel routes after filter
     *
     */
    'stats_routes_after_filter' => '',
    /*
     * Stats Panel routes middleware
     *
     */
    'stats_routes_middleware' => 'web',
    /*
     * Stats Panel template path
     */
    'stats_template_path' => '/templates/sb-admin-2',
    /*
     * Stats Panel base uri.
     *
     * If your site url is http://wwww.mysite.com, then your stats page will be:
     *
     *    http://wwww.mysite.com/stats
     *
     */
    'stats_base_uri' => 'admin/stats',
    /*
     * Stats Panel layout view
     */
    'stats_layout' => 'pragmarx/tracker::layout',
    /*
     * Stats Panel controllers namespace
     */
    'stats_controllers_namespace' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Controllers',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it needs separate models. If you ran the `php artisan vendor:publish` command, the public files it requires should be available to you in 5.4.

Your options file specifies that it's using the App\User model already and I don't think it needs any other one. You do need to change this line:     `'stats_panel_enabled' => false` to `true`. Also, did you set an is_admin attribute on App\User as specified in the last step?

Does anything show up in the database tables even if you can't get to the tracker view?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  That did give me one step closer, however no one in trade access the stats page I have setup in the configuration file, I get the error of “User model misses admin property.” I did a search on this error with all of the previous conclusions not working.  // Added info above//I’m still not getting any tracker functions to return with activity or seeing any new records in my database for tracker tables.  So I’m one step closer, but still have a few issues